# How to get Logic Pro X to record keyboard sounds?

Tags: keyboard, midi, logic-pro, computer

I have A Juno DS88, which should be able to send audio data. I also have Logic Pro X on my mac. I've been able to use it like a MIDI controller, but I'm trying to record the sounds my Juno gives me onto my computer.  I think it's something to do with what I need to do in my DAW so if there are any Logic users around that would be or even if you're not.

Comment: I've noticed that you have posted this seem question twice before in previous months. Can you be more specific about where in the process you are having trouble? Your Juno DS88 is capable of doing this without the need for an audio interface, although the methods suggested below will also work.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question over and over again. If you still don't understand how to do this, edit your question to include more information, or comment on the answers to your previous question asking for more detail.

Comment: How would I do this without an audio interface, I do not know the exact process. If there is a tutorial someone could link me to or somehow I'm missing something in the process that's all I'd like to know. The problem is I don't know what to do on my computer or on Logic Pro X to let it record the sounds.

Comment: The top answer right below this tells you exactly step by step how to do this without an interface. What do you feel is missing from the process? Perhaps try following the steps and asking a new question if you get stuck on a step.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's been asked before by the same user a gew times.

Comment: Close the other ones this one contains good answers for people to use.

Answer (score 2):

The Roland Juno-DS can send audio to your DAW over USB; this will give you better audio quality than connecting the Juno's audio outputs to an audio interface, because the audio isn't converted to analog and back to digital.

**To set-up the Juno-DS to work with USB:**

- Press `MENU`
- Move the cursor to `SYSTEM` and press `ENTER`
- Use the arrow left/right buttons to select the `MIDI` tab at the top of the screen
- Move the cursor to `USB Driver` and set this to `Vendor`
- Move the cursor to `WRITE` and press `ENTER` to save this setting
- Switch the power off and back on again

**To install the Juno-DS USB driver on your computer:**

On some operating systems, the driver will be automatically downloaded and installed when you connect the Juno-DS to the computer with the USB cable. If not:

- Go to https://www.roland.com/us/products/juno-ds/juno-ds88/
- Click on `Downloads`
- Download the "JUNO-DS Driver" for your operating system and version
- Look for a file called `setup` in the content of the download, and run it
- During installation of the driver, you may be asked to restart your computer

**To check that the Juno-DS is properly connected:**

In Mac OSX, look in the Audio MIDI Setup utility and confirm that the Juno-DS is listed in both the Audio and MIDI Studio windows.

In Windows, open the Device Manager and confirm that the Juno-DS is listed under Sound, Video and Game Controllers.

**To select the Juno-DS as a sound source in Logic Pro X:**

- Open the `Preferences` and then the `Audio` menu
- Click the `Devices` tab
- Select the Juno-DS as the `Input Device`
- Click on `Apply Changes`

Comment: Note that for this particular asker, it must be a Mac because Logic Pro x is not available for Windows.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Indeed; I forgot for a minute how Apple bought Emagic and screwed over the Logic for Windows users :-)

Comment: Thank you. However the what my Input Devices are listed as are: System Setting, USB Audio Device, Macbook Pro Microphone. Output Devices: System Setting, USB Audio Device, Macbook Pro Speakers,  JUNO-DS. There is no JUNO-DS for the input, only USB Audio Device. Is this a problem with my driver?

Comment: @JoeyPeluka Sounds like a driver problem indeed. You could try removing the driver and reinstalling it. Also make sure you have the latest version of the Juno's system software installed (currently 2.10). If that doesn't help, you should probably contact Roland support, or see if they have an online troubleshooting forum.

Comment: Thanks. My keyboard says System Version: 1.06 in the information tab if that tells anything. Either way, would I need to download both the driver and the Juno system program thing?

Comment: @JoeyPeluka Yes, they're both on the Roland site that I linked to in my answer. But make sure to read the instructions on the site before updating the system. Updating the system could fix compatibility problems with OSX versions that came out after you bought the Juno (but the problem may still be elsewhere, of course).

Comment: Okay I see the instructions and they seem simple enough except for this first part:  "Copy the update-use file ( juno_ds_up.bin ) to the root directory of the USB Flash Memory." Also I'm not sure what it means by the "TAP" button later in . the instructions. Not sure if these are things you might know about?

Comment: @JoeyPeluka The instruction about the "root directory" means that you should copy the file to the USB stick, but not put it in a folder (the USB stick should be formatted in the Juno-DS if it isn't already, by selecting `FORMAT USB MEMORY` in the `UTILITY` menu). The `TAP` button is a button on the Juno-DS panel in the "phrase pad" section; keeping it pressed while switching on the Juno-DS tells the device that you want to perform a system upgrade.

Comment: I appreciate you sticking around to try and get through all this. However I'm not extremely knowledgable with computers and really don't know anything of what "juno_ds_up.bin",  or usb stick is. Is this a file I download on my computer or something like that?

Comment: @JoeyPeluka The system update you can download is a compressed "zip" file. Double-clicking it should produce the "bin" file in the same folder. This should be copied to a USB flash drive (any brand or type or size will do; the file is only 4MB) which has first been formatted in the Juno-DS. (You can buy USB flash drives for $5 or less: https://www.amazon.com/Kingston-Digital-DataTraveler-DTSE9H-32GBZ/dp/B006W8U2WU/ )